# Grails 3 Spring security tags in gsp

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, grails-3.0

Since Spring Security Core Plugin is not currently working for Grails 3, I am trying to use Spring boot as indicated [here](http://spiesdavid.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/grails-3-app-with-security-part-1.html) for authorization. Please give some hint how to display current user's name in gsp. Is there any way to use Spring Security's tags in the gsp files.
Thanks

Comment: Great question - haven't yet been able to get the GSP to recognise the spring security tag libs. Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Unknown JSP tag sec:authorize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [tag library](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#taglibs) has access to the `session` and can be used to display the current username.

In the GSP, put:

```
<g:username />
```

Then create a TagLib such as:

**grails-app/taglib/SecurityTagLib.groovy**

```
class SecurityTagLib {

   def username = {
      def token = session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.getAuthentication()
      out << token?.getPrincipal()?.getUsername()
      }

}
```

Comment: You aren't seriously suggesting people build their own tag libraries because grails GSP pages don't support the standard spring security tag libraries are you?  Yuck

Comment: Yes.  1) Tag libraries are lightweight and easy to create and 2) alternatives, such as customizing the plug-in, are more involved.  That being said, it sure would be nice if the plug-in had a `username` tag built in by default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, appreciate that tag creation is quite straightforward so in that sense, yes rather than customizing a plugin, it is the better of two evils. But I was really hoping that there would be drop in support for Spring Security Tag lib or an equivalent replacement - it sounds like what I need to build (for my usecase) is a GSP friendly spring security tag lib, and that does come as a surprise.  Any ideas?

Comment: I usually end up with various handy security tags defined in the project's `SecurityTagLib.groovy` file.  It's effectively a "GSP friendly spring security tag lib", but it's really tied to the project not to the Spring Security plugin.

Comment: Could you share the contents of one of your SecurityTagLIb.groovy files? Gist on github etc? Really welcome having a stencil to follow, and thank you very much for your replies and recommendations.

Comment: Are you basically copying contents of something like this: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SecurityTagLib.groovy

Answer (score 0):

I implemented stripped down versions of the `SpringSecurityService` and `SecurityTagLib` within my application, based on the latest Grails 2 plugin. Its a source based plugin, you can simply copy the required tags.